Infinite sequence of PSD non-moments in two variables
Define a 2d sequence to be a mapping $a: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ (where $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, \dots\}$). Here are two definitions of types of 2d sequences:

We say that a 2d sequence $a$ is a moment sequence if it is possible to have random variables $X, Y$ drawn from a probability distribution $\mathcal{D}$ such that for all $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $\mathbb{E}_{(X, Y) \sim \mathcal{D}}[X^i Y^j] = a(i, j)$.
We say that a 2d sequence $a$ is a PSD sequence if for all $n$, for all $(i_1, j_1), \dots, (i_n, j_n)$, the $n \times n$ matrix $M$ whose $(k, \ell)$-entry is $a(i_k + i_\ell, j_k + j_\ell)$ is positive semidefinite.

My question: is every PSD sequence $a$ with $a(0, 0) = 1$ also a moment sequence? And if not, what is a specific example of a PSD sequence that is not a moment sequence?
(The statement would be true if I had asked about 1d sequences: see the Hamburger moment problem.)
(Note also that the converse of my question is true: every moment sequence is a PSD sequence. To see this, consider any moment sequence $a$ and let $\mathcal{D}$ be a distribution over random variables $(X, Y)$ such that their moments are described by $a$. Choose any $n, (i_1, j_1), \dots, (i_n, j_n)$. To show that the corresponding matrix $M$ is PSD, consider any vector $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\mathbf{v}^\top M \mathbf{v} = \mathbb{E}_{(X, Y) \sim \mathcal{D}}[(v_1 X^{i_1} Y^{j_1} + \dots + v_n X^{i_n} Y^{j_n})^2] \ge 0$.)
These lecture notes seem helpful, but they are specifically concerned with degree-$d$ moments for fixed $d$, whereas I'm interested in the entire infinite sequence of moments.

This is not true. See the discussion in Section 5.1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.12698

Thanks. I'm not yet clear on how to derive a specific example of a PSD sequence that's not a moment sequence using the Motzkin polynomial (or any given positive polynomial that's not a sum of squares) -- how do you do that?
